# Why is the slope not coinciding with the line?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

So, I went to desmos website and drew two graphs. One was the graph of $y=x$ and another was the graph of $y=1$.
The graphs came out to be something like this
[image]

But, shouldn't the line y=1 coincide with y=x, because, it's the equation of the slope of y=x. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Guys, there is no reason to downvote this question. It's an honest question that the OP is confused about.

Comment: @5xum Thanks for understanding. You are the only one who understands this. I had an honest doubt and thats it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue line (graph of the function $f(x)=x$) is the **derivative** of the red line (graph of the function $g(x)=1$). At each point on the red line, the slope (i.e., the tangent of the angle between the horizontal line and the red line) is equal to $1$ (which is the value of the blue line).

The two lines do not coincide, because the two functions are not the same function.

Comment: I get it now. The slope at every point of the function y=x is 1, so, its making an angle 45 degrees as its evident from the graph. Also y=x and y=1 are two separate functions and the latter having no effect on the former.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x $ is the diagonal.   $y=1$ is horizontal, at height 1.   They're two different lines. In general,  functions don't equal their derivatives...  On the contrary, the  derivative function just gives the slope of the tangent to the (original) function at each argument value. ..